# Tryint to generate "Cloud Endpoint Client Library" from Google-app-engine project failed in MAC OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-app-engine

I'm trying to generate "Cloud Endpoint Client Library" from Google App-Engine project using Eclipse plug-in, but it fails with exception: InvocationTargetException - "All API classes with the same API name and version must have the exact same API-wide configuration".
I'm using Eclipse 4.2 with Google App-Engine plug-in 1.8.3 on MAC OS X 10.8.4.
The strange thing is: on PC running Windows with same eclipse and plug-in versions, generating the libraries from the project doesn't raise any exception.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Eclipse 4.2, App Engine 1.8.4 on Windows. And it's the MobileAssistant sample app. Have you resolved this issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.
I ended up removing the resource attribute from ALL of the endpoint classes, as it was the only difference.

```
@Api(name = "shoppingassistant",
// resource = "deviceinfos",
version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = ApiKeysAndIds.API_OWNER, ownerName = ApiKeysAndIds.API_OWNER, packagePath = ApiKeysAndIds.API_PACKAGE_PATH), clientIds = {
        ApiKeysAndIds.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, ApiKeysAndIds.IOS_CLIENT_ID, ApiKeysAndIds.WEB_CLIENT_ID }, audiences = { ApiKeysAndIds.AUDIENCE_ID })
```

The project compiles now, and I was able to generate the client lib.
(I haven't tried the android project yet)

Answer (score 0):

While all properties in the @Api annotation must match for all classes in an API, you can additionally use the @ApiClass annotation to provides properties that do not need to be exactly the same between classes.

For this case:

```
@Api(name = "shoppingassistant",
version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = ApiKeysAndIds.API_OWNER,
    ownerName = ApiKeysAndIds.API_OWNER, packagePath = ApiKeysAndIds.API_PACKAGE_PATH),
clientIds = {
    ApiKeysAndIds.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, ApiKeysAndIds.IOS_CLIENT_ID, ApiKeysAndIds.WEB_CLIENT_ID},
audiences = {ApiKeysAndIds.AUDIENCE_ID})
@ApiClass(resource = "deviceinfos")
```

Read the full tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass#using_apiclass_for_properties_that_can_differ_between_classes)